# module 'importlib' has no attribute 'util'

Tags: python, python-3.x, raspberry-pi, python-importlib

I am using Python 3.7 on my raspberry pi3, I got an error that my module importlib doesn't have util, could you tell me how resolve this problem?

If I do:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ python3
>>> import importlib
>>> dir(importlib)
```

I get :

```
['_RELOADING', '__all__', '__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__import__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__spec__', '_bootstrap', '_bootstrap_external', '_imp', '_r_long', '_w_long', 'find_loader', 'import_module', 'invalidate_caches', 'reload', 'sys', 'types', 'warnings']
```

So :

```
>>> importlib.util
```

returns:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 1, in 
AttributeError: module 'importlib' has no attribute 'util'

I tried with Python 3.8 but I got the same results
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to do `import importlib.util`:

```
>>> import importlib.util
>>> dir(importlib.util)
['LazyLoader', 'MAGIC_NUMBER', '_LazyModule', '_RAW_MAGIC_NUMBER', '__builtins__',
'__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', 
'__spec__', '_find_spec', '_find_spec_from_path', '_imp', '_module_to_load',
'_resolve_name', 'abc', 'cache_from_source', 'contextmanager', 'decode_source',
'find_spec', 'functools', 'module_for_loader', 'module_from_spec', 'resolve_name',
'set_loader', 'set_package', 'source_from_cache', 'source_hash',
'spec_from_file_location', 'spec_from_loader', 'sys', 'types', 'warnings']
>>>
```

relevant docs: [importlib.util](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#module-importlib.util)